# Не работает js после после генерации статического проекта на NUXT JS

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, build, generate

Собственно, создаю чистый проект на NUXT JS. Добавляю код для проверки JS

```
<script>
export default {
   mounted() {
      alert( 'ok' )
   }
}
</script>
```

. Выполняю команды `npm run build` и `npm run generate`, чтобы собрать статичный сайт. Создается папка dist. Открываю dist -> index.html. HTML и CSS работает, а js нет.
Были ошибки что не найдены js файлы.

В `nuxt.config` я указал путь `router: {base:'/nuxt/test/dist'}`, либо  `router: {base:'./'}` тоже работает.
Ошибки исчезли, никаких ошибок больше нет. Но js всё так же не работает. В чем может быть проблема?
В режиме разработки `npm run dev`, всё ок!

Так выглядит `nuxt.config`

```
export default {
   target: 'static',

   head: {
      title: 'test1',
      meta: [
         {charset: 'utf-8'},
         {name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1'},
         {hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: ''}
      ],
      link: [
         {rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico'}
      ]
   },

   css: [],

   plugins: [],

   components: true,

   buildModules: [],

   modules: [],

   build: {
   },
   router: {
      base: './'
   }

}
```

Comment: Вы проверяете работу JS файла только указав в хуке alert? Почему alert, а не console.log? Недавно стали изучать vue + nuxt?

Comment: Да, я не сильно опытен. Так же проверял на динамическом добавлении классов. Тоже не работает. Разве имеет значение какое событие сработает при проверке работы js?

Comment: нет, неважно. но использование alert вместо console.log почему-то активно навязываться learn.javascript.ru. я бы советовал отходить от этой практики и юзать консоль лог

Comment: не вижу в конфиге строки script: [{ src: 'путь к файлу', body: true }]

Comment: @user419140, вам нужно развернуть содержимое директории `dist` в корневую директорию вашего сервера или использовать команду `npm run start` для проверки работы из локальной директории.

Comment: `npm run start` работает замечательно. Загрузил на github  - всё ок, работает! Единственное не работает только локально, когда запускаю index.html из папки dist. Не знаю как это работает, но, я так понял это нормальное явление.

Comment: Еще такой момент, что на github не будет работать, если файлы загружать из папки `dist` перетаскиванием вручную через `upload files`. Github почему то игнорирует файл `.nojekyll` и не загружает его. Если загрузить на github через консоль, то файл  `.nojekyll` загружается и всё работает как надо.